# Phrase & wildcard queries on Elasticsearch

Tags: html, elasticsearch, wildcard, phrase

I am facing some difficulties while trying to create a query that can match only whole phrases, but allows wildcards as well.

Basically I have a filed that contains a string (it is actually a list of strings, but for simplicity I am skipping that), which can contain white spaces or be null, lets call it "color".

For example:

```
{
  ...
  "color": "Dull carmine pink"
  ...
}
```

My queries need to be able to do the following:

- search for null values (inclusive and exclusive)
- search for non null values (inclusive and exclusive)
- search for and match only a whole phrase (inclusive and exclusive). For example:

  - dull carmine pink --> match
  - carmine pink --> not a match
- same as the last, but with wildcards (inclusive and exclusive). For example:

  - ?ull carmine p* --> match to "Dull carmine pink"
  - dull carmine* -> match to "Dull carmine pink"
  - etc.

I have been bumping my head against the wall for a few days with this and I have tried almost every type of query I could think of.

I have only managed to make it work partially with a span_near query with the help of [this topic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/wildcard-with-exact-phrase-search-using-query-string/102631/3).

So basically I can now:

- search for a whole phrase with/without wildcards like this:

  ```
  {
      "span_near": {
          "clauses": [
              {
                  "span_term": {"color": "dull"}
              },
              {
                  "span_term": {"color": "carmine"}
              },
              {
                  "span_multi": {"match": {"wildcard": {"color": "p*"}}}
              }
          ],
          "slop": 0,
          "in_order": true
      }
  }
  ```
- search for null values (inclusive and exclusive) by simple must/must_not queries like this:

  ```
  {
     "must" / "must_not": {'exist': {'field': 'color'}}
  }
  ```

**The problem:**
I cannot find a way to make an exclusive span query. The only way I can find is [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-not-query.html). But it requires both include & exclude fields, and I am only trying to exclude some fields, all others must be returned. Is there some analog of the "match_all":{} query that can work inside of an span_not's include field? Or perhaps an entire new, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution a month ago, but I forgot to post it here.
I do not have an example at hand, but I will try to explain it.

The problem was that the fields I was trying to query were analyzed by elasticsearch before querying. The analyzer in question was dividing them by spaces etc. The solution to this problem is one of the two:

**1.** **If you do not use a custom mapping for the index.**

(Meaning if you let elasticsearch to dynamically create the appropriate mapping for your field when you were adding it).

In this case elastic search automatically creates a subfield of the text field called "keyword". This subfield uses the "keyword" analyzer which does not process the data in any way prior to querying.

Which means that queries like:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [ // must_not
            {
                "match": {
                    "user.keyword": "Kim Chy"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}
and

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [ // must_not
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "user.keyword": "Kim*y"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

should work as expected.

However with the default mapping, the keyword field will most likely be case-sensitive. In order for it to be case-insensitive as well, you will need to create a custom mapping, that applies a lower-case (or upper-case) **normalizer** to the query and keyword field prior to matching.

**2. If you use a custom mapping**

Basically the same as above, however you will have to create a new subfield (or field) manually that uses the keyword analyzer (and possibly a normalizer in order for it to be case-insensitive).

**P.S.** As far as I am aware changing of a mapping is no longer possible in elasticsearch. This means that you will have to create a new index with the appropriate mapping, and then reindex your data to the new index.

Comment: Suppose, user.keyword have two possibilities, "Kim*y" & "Abc*yz" then!!!

Comment: Any way to make it search all subfields using wildcard i.e. user.* .. I tried but es didn't return anything so I guess it doesn't like it